# New to SQL. Query SQL database using info across three tables

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is using phpMyAdmin.

I need to find the contact information for Subscribers who have pending Orders on November 15th.  Their contact information is stored in a table called Subscribers, and the primary key is  UID (User ID).  The Subscriptions Table has a primary key called SID (Subscriptions ID).  The Subscriptions table also stores the UID for each Subscription.  However, the Orders table is where the Date is stored, and this table stores the SID but not the UID, so I can't directly JOIN Orders with Subscribers.

I have to  JOIN Orders with Subscriptions on SID where the Orders Date is 11-15-10, and then I have to  JOIN the resulting table with the Subscribers table on UID.

I'm currently trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM Subscribers
RIGHT JOIN (Orders a, Subscriptions b, Subscribers c)
ON (a.SID = b.SID AND b.UID = c.UID)
WHERE a.Date = '2010-11-01'
```

This is causing a massive lag followed by Gateway Timeout.

This is a classic case of knowing what to do, but not knowing how to do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT
    scrb.*
FROM
    Subscribers scrb
WHERE
    scrb.UID in (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            scrp.UID
        FROM
            Subscriptions scrp
            INNER JOIN Orders ordr ON
                ordr.SID = scrp.SID
        WHERE
            ordr.Date = STR_TO_DATE('2010-11-01')
    )
```

Not sure if you're going to have a big performance improvement though... Maybe your tables miss a better indexing strategy...?

In fact, you should try executing just the inner query (`SELECT DISTINCT scrp.UID...`) first... If it is too slow, I would guess your problem is on the `Orders.Date` field - a full scan over that table probably has a high performance cost.

Comment: Can you explain a little of what you're doing?  I'm lost.  What is "scrb.*"?

Comment: 1) The inner query is selecting all subscriptions on 2010-11-01. 2) Then the outer query is selecting all subscribers with the same UID as the UID stored on those subscriptions selected on the inner query. Hope I made it clearer...

Comment: @CAN Wizard "scrb" is the alias @rsenna has given to the Subscribers table. "scrb.*" will return all rows from that table.

Comment: hm... Sorry about that, I always use 4-digit aliases... :P

Comment: For some reason, I got a "Page not found" error with this SQL script.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Yeah!  It finally worked!  Not sure why it didn't work earlier, but it does now!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you join Subscribers to Subscribers?
`SELECT * FROM Subscribers ... JOIN ... Subscribers c)`

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited amount we know about your schema, it seems like you'd do better with an `INNER JOIN`, which will filter records for you, and @seriyPS is right about the redundant Subscribers table - currently, this query as written is performing a `CROSS JOIN`, joining all Subscribers to every result of Subscriber joined to Subscription joined to Order...

Is there a reason why this won't work?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Subscribers a
INNER JOIN Subscriptions b ON a.UID = b.UID
INNER JOIN Orders c ON b.SID = c.SID
WHERE c.Date = '2010-11-01'
```

Comment: This also caused a Gateway Timeout

Comment: Exactly how much data is in these tables / Can you control the timeout duration in (I assume from the tag on your question that you're using) phpMyAdmin?